# why django don`t work on domain? but work on server ip address

Tags: django, nginx, apache2

i have buyed domen example.ru and server ip adress 111.11.1.11

when i visit 111.11.1.11 my home page loads and works fine
but when i visit example.ru my home page doesn't work

oh, and the main, when i visit example.ru/auth/login the page loads fine
that is, when I load a link with a directory, everything works, but the main domain address does not want to load

my nginx site file:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name justdo-fulfillment.localhost;
    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location /static/ {
        root /opt/justdo_full_site;
    }

    location / {
        include proxy_params;
        proxy_pass http://unix:/run/gunicorn.sock;
    }
}
```

Comment: i have a new info, in chrome incognita my domain loads fine, but in standart it doesn't works((

Comment: Clear your browser cache.